# NSClassFromString found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, xcode6

I've created some Inheritance on a view and I want to try to handle on the abstract view class a way to create a viewController according to the dynamic name of the view class. Here is what i do :

```
    let className = NSObject.getClassNameFromDynamicType(self)
    var viewControllerName = NSString(format: "%@ViewController", className)

    // Create view controller from widgetType
    var anyobjectype :AnyObject.Type =  NSClassFromString(viewControllerName)
    var nsobjectype : UIViewController.Type = anyobjectype as UIViewController.Type
```

and the getClassNameFromDynamicType method :

```
class func getClassNameFromDynamicType(thing:AnyObject) -> String {
    var complexClassName = NSStringFromClass(thing.dynamicType)
    return complexClassName.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
}
```

This method return me the correct string : "MyCustomViewController"
But i got a

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on the call to

```
var anyobjectype :AnyObject.Type =  NSClassFromString(viewControllerName)
```

The debugger show me that viewcontrollerName is not nil and has the correct value. 
What am I missing ?

Comment: `AnyObject.Type` is also known as `AnyClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you have to prefix the class name with the module name. So if your module is called `MyProject` and the class you are instantiating is `MyViewController`, you should use `MyProject.MyViewController`.

If you're not sure what your module name is, I find easy to read it by opening any storyboard, selecting any view controller, and looking at the Identity Inspector (it's the 2nd field).

Comment: Thanks that was it ! What if this is designed to be integrated (maybe later as a cocoaPod), what would be in this case the modulename ? MyPodName.ViewController or TheUserProject.ViewController ?

Comment: Never tried, but I'm sure it's the module in which it is defined. The module name is like namespaces in java and C#

Comment: Maybe usefull for some people in the future : That came from my getClassNameFromDynamicType where I removed it before returning it